# Maps, test if current location is on or near polyline

Tags: android, google-maps, maps

I'm using google directions api to draw a polyline for a route. Does anyone have any examples of checking if current location is on/near a polyline? Trying to determine if users current location is within x meters of that line and if not i'll make a new request and redraw a new route.

Cheers!

Comment: This [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16429562/find-a-point-in-a-polyline-which-is-closest-to-a-latlng) might be helpful.

Comment: The response to this thread should help You greatly http://stackoverflow.com/a/25198514/7725722

Answer (score 4):

Here is my solution: just add the `bdccGeoDistanceAlgorithm` class I have created to your project and use `bdccGeoDistanceCheckWithRadius` method to check if your current location is on or near polyline (polyline equals to a list of LatLng of points)
Your can also get the distance from the method

Class `bdccGeoDistanceAlgorithm`

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

import java.util.List;

public class bdccGeoDistanceAlgorithm {

// distance in meters from GLatLng point to GPolyline or GPolygon poly
public static boolean bdccGeoDistanceCheckWithRadius(List<LatLng> poly, LatLng point, int radius)
{
    int i;
    bdccGeo p = new bdccGeo(point.latitude,point.longitude);

    for(i=0; i < (poly.size()-1) ; i++)
    {
        LatLng p1 = poly.get(i);
        bdccGeo l1 = new bdccGeo(p1.latitude,p1.longitude);

        LatLng p2 = poly.get(i+1);
        bdccGeo l2 = new bdccGeo(p2.latitude,p2.longitude);

        double distance = p.function_distanceToLineSegMtrs(l1, l2);

        if(distance < radius)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}


// object

public static class bdccGeo
{
    public double lat;
    public double lng;

    public double x;
    public double y;
    public double z;


    public bdccGeo(double lat, double lon) {
        this.lat = lat;
        this.lng = lng;

        double theta = (lon * Math.PI / 180.0);
        double rlat = function_bdccGeoGeocentricLatitude(lat * Math.PI / 180.0);
        double c = Math.cos(rlat);
        this.x = c * Math.cos(theta);
        this.y = c * Math.sin(theta);
        this.z = Math.sin(rlat);
    }

    //returns in meters the minimum of the perpendicular distance of this point from the line segment geo1-geo2
    //and the distance from this point to the line segment ends in geo1 and geo2
    public double function_distanceToLineSegMtrs(bdccGeo geo1,bdccGeo geo2)
    {

        //point on unit sphere above origin and normal to plane of geo1,geo2
        //could be either side of the plane
        bdccGeo p2 = geo1.function_crossNormalize(geo2);

        // intersection of GC normal to geo1/geo2 passing through p with GC geo1/geo2
        bdccGeo ip = function_bdccGeoGetIntersection(geo1,geo2,this,p2);

        //need to check that ip or its antipode is between p1 and p2
        double d = geo1.function_distance(geo2);
        double d1p = geo1.function_distance(ip);
        double d2p = geo2.function_distance(ip);
        //window.status = d + ", " + d1p + ", " + d2p;
        if ((d >= d1p) && (d >= d2p))
            return function_bdccGeoRadiansToMeters(this.function_distance(ip));
        else
        {
            ip = ip.function_antipode();
            d1p = geo1.function_distance(ip);
            d2p = geo2.function_distance(ip);
        }
        if ((d >= d1p) && (d >= d2p))
            return function_bdccGeoRadiansToMeters(this.function_distance(ip));
        else
            return function_bdccGeoRadiansToMeters(Math.min(geo1.function_distance(this),geo2.function_distance(this)));
    }

    // More Maths
    public bdccGeo function_crossNormalize(bdccGeo b)
    {
        double x = (this.y * b.z) - (this.z * b.y);
        double y = (this.z * b.x) - (this.x * b.z);
        double z = (this.x * b.y) - (this.y * b.x);
        double L = Math.sqrt((x * x) + (y * y) + (z * z));
        bdccGeo r = new bdccGeo(0,0);
        r.x = x / L;
        r.y = y / L;
        r.z = z / L;

        return r;
    }

    // Returns the two antipodal points of intersection of two great
    // circles defined by the arcs geo1 to geo2 and
    // geo3 to geo4. Returns a point as a Geo, use .antipode to get the other point
    public bdccGeo function_bdccGeoGetIntersection(bdccGeo geo1,bdccGeo  geo2, bdccGeo geo3,bdccGeo geo4)
    {
        bdccGeo geoCross1 = geo1.function_crossNormalize(geo2);
        bdccGeo geoCross2 = geo3.function_crossNormalize(geo4);
        return geoCross1.function_crossNormalize(geoCross2);
    }

    public double function_distance(bdccGeo v2)
    {
        return Math.atan2(v2.function_crossLength(this), v2.function_dot(this));
    }

    //More Maths
    public double function_crossLength(bdccGeo b)
    {
        double x = (this.y * b.z) - (this.z * b.y);
        double y = (this.z * b.x) - (this.x * b.z);
        double z = (this.x * b.y) - (this.y * b.x);
        return Math.sqrt((x * x) + (y * y) + (z * z));
    }

    //Maths
    public double function_dot(bdccGeo b)
    {
        return ((this.x * b.x) + (this.y * b.y) + (this.z * b.z));
    }

    //from Radians to Meters
    public double function_bdccGeoRadiansToMeters(double rad)
    {
        return rad * 6378137.0; // WGS84 Equatorial Radius in Meters
    }

    // point on opposite side of the world to this point
    public bdccGeo function_antipode()
    {
        return this.function_scale(-1.0);
    }

    //More Maths
    public bdccGeo function_scale(double s)
    {
        bdccGeo r = new bdccGeo(0,0);
        r.x = this.x * s;
        r.y = this.y * s;
        r.z = this.z * s;
        return r;
    }

    // Convert from geographic to geocentric latitude (radians).
    public double function_bdccGeoGeocentricLatitude(double geographicLatitude)
    {
        double flattening = 1.0 / 298.257223563;//WGS84
        double f = (1.0 - flattening) * (1.0 - flattening);
        return Math.atan((Math.tan(geographicLatitude) * f));
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Distance get in which format.? In Meter, Radius, Centimeter or what.?

Comment: Distance in meters. I write it in the comment line above